# Eclipse reference and declaration context menu options missing when in a JSP file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, reference, contextmenu, definition

I'm using Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and the ctrl-g and ctrl-shift-g short cuts do not work when editing a JSP file.  References from JSP files to functions are not shown when checking from java files and vs vs for declarations.  It all works fine within a java file.  The reference and declaration context menu options are also missing when I right click a function so this doesn't seem to be a hot-key problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: One more good reason to never, ever, put Java code in JSPs. Put Java code in Java classes. Use JSPs as a pure view technology, responsible for generating HTML with the JSP EL, the JSTL, and data stored by a controller written in Java in request attributes. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: It hasn't worked for a while but it used to work fine.  It a real productivity killer.  I'm thinking along the lines of a wrong compiler setting.  Having said that I like to use java functions in JSP.  It makes JSP a very powerful UI tool as long as functionality is segregated into a MVC model

Comment: Update.  So I have installed Neon and still am missing java level tools such as reference and definitions for JSP files.  The problem almost seems like the JSP editor isn't aware there is Java code in the file.  Are there content type settings that may need to be enabled for JSP files?  Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.